# Custom header in NSMutableRequest

Tags: iphone, ios

I wants to include my own custom header in the NSMutableRequest. I have used

```
[request addValue:(some string value) forHTTPHeaderField:(some string value)];
```

but its not working. Where am i wrong?

Comment: Could you elaborate how _its not working_?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `- (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field` ?

Comment: @Amar Actually server is checking the header string. If it matches then only i shall get positive response. But it is not returning me that.

Comment: @j_freyre I have tried with that too. Its not working.

Comment: @hawkeye_01 If you have access to the server, you can check the headers of incoming request. If specific header is not observed in the request you should check your iOS code if header is getting set correctly or not.

Comment: I dont have access to the server.